# Passing a Javascript variable to Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I made a JavaScript/jQuery game using that and HTML CSS. Now I am trying to integrate said game into a Django backend. Currently, I have a `.js` file that contains all of my Javascript/jQuery logic. It is `<linked>`'ed to the HTML page and basically controls the entire flow of the game.

*How do I access a JavaScript variable within my `.js` file in my Django*

***.js code...***
I want the `this.clicks` variable to be accessible in my Django view.

```
this.total = 18
this.clicks = 0
this.move = function(num){  //Adds or subtracts one from total depending on which player calls it
    if(this.total == 0){
        $('#oneone').show();
    }else if(this.total == 36){
        $('#twoform').show();
    }else{
        this.total += num
        this.clicks += 1
        return this.total
    }
}
```

***Django view...***

```
class EndGame(View):
    def get(self, request, victor, gameid, player1id, player2id):
        print(gameid)
        if int(victor) == 1:  ##player one
            self.TallyUpScore(1, player1id, player2id)
            self.UpdateGameStats(1, gameid)
        else:  ##player two
            self.TallyUpScore(2, player1id, player2id)
            self.UpdateGameStats(2, gameid)
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, its essentially asking for a tutorial on how to post data with an ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to retrieve the csrf token:

```
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;

        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return cookieValue;
     }
```

then using ajax to send your data to your django view:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
    },
    url:  'here_your_view_url/' + this.clicks,
    type: "GET",
    success:function(response){
        //alert("success: " + response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        //alert("failure: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    //alert("end");
});
```

**views.py**

```
    def my_view(request):
        clicks = request.GET.get('clicks')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^here_your_view_url/(?P<clicks>\d+)', 'my_view')
```

I will recommend to check [Django Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax) for more details.

Comment: getting `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
`  error any thoughts?

Comment: I get an insanely large object full of stuff

Comment: I did and it threw me this error... `TypeError: post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: I am using class based views